# Spring Security bulk password hashing

Tags: hibernate, security, spring-security, sql-update, bulk

I implemented Spring Security using hashed passwords. Now I need to update all passwords in plain text to be hashed. Problem is that I have over 120000 users and it takes too much time to update it in Java (using Hibernate)

Is there a better way to do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your operation is consuming lot of time because of high no of database hits. You can minimize them -

1. First do **bcp out** to a file

   `bcp db.my_table  encrypted_file.txt -c -t\t -b{batch_size} -S{your_server} -U{username} -P{password}`
2. Then process the file and encrypt all the plain password
3. Now do **bcp in**

   `bcp db.my_table in encrypted_file.txt -c -t\t -b{batch_size} -S{your_server} -U{username} -P{password}`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does support some [encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). For example, if you use SHA-1, you would just need to call something like this

```
update user set password = SHA1(password)
```

Comment: I use org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder in my application. Is there a MySQL alternative for that?

Comment: You can try with `ENCRYPT` function but it won't work on Windows since it uses the OS (Unix) `crypt()` function.